# sock.io io.to(sockid) didn't work in Express+ React

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I tried to build a real-time chat room , but there's something wrong , here's my code

```js
const addUser = (userId:string,socketId:string)=>{
        !users.some(user=>user.userId===userId) &&
            users.push({userId,socketId});
    }
const removeUser = (socketId:string)=>{
        users = users.filter(user=>user.socketId !== socketId)
    }
const getUser = (userId:string)=>{
        return users.find(user=>user.userId === userId)
    }
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
        //when connect
        console.log(users)
        io.emit("getMessage",{
          message:"good"
        })
        //take userId and socketId from user
        socket.on("addUser",userId=>{
            addUser(userId,socket.id);
            console.log(users)
            io.emit("getUsers",users)
        })
        //send and get message
        socket.on("sendMessage",({ senderId,receiverId,text})=>{
            const user = getUser(receiverId); //use receiverId to find it's socketId
            console.log(users)
            console.log(user.socketId)
            io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage",{ //did'nt work
              senderId,
              text, 
            });
            // io.emit("getMessage",{   //it works
            //   senderId,
            //   text, 
            // })
        })
        //when disconnect
        socket.on("disconnect",()=>{
            console.log("a user disconnected")
            removeUser(socket.id);
            io.emit("getUsers",users)
        })
    })
```

Client side

```js
const socket = useRef();
useEffect(()=>{
        const getOnline = async()=>{
            socket.current = await io(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_PORT)   
            socket.current.on("getMessage",data=>{
                console.log("Message",data)
                setArrivalMessage({
                    sender: data.senderId,
                    text: data.text,
                    createdAt: Date.now(),
                })
            })
        }
        getOnline();     
    },[])
const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(socket.current.id)
        const message = {
            sender: user._id,
            text: newMessage.current.value,
            conversationId : currentChat._id,
        };
        const receiverId = currentChat.members.find(
            (member)=> member !== user._id
        );

        socket.current.emit("sendMessage",{
            senderId: user._id,
            receiverId,
            text:newMessage.current.value,
        })
        console.log(user._id)
        console.log(receiverId)
        //database insertion......
    };
```

So everything work fine except sending message, when I tired to send message to specific socket id , it won't work , so I tried emit to send to everyone, it works,then I think it might be the socket Id problem , so I did the following socket id printing at both side.

Server side console

```
611dc227ccbf0ca9d2193b37 Hi 611de1937df523af1ffd42f8 
[ // people who connect to this socket ,you can see the logic above
  { 
    userId: '611dc227ccbf0ca9d2193b37',
    socketId: 'R0aR7RPkiaH-Ai8qAAAR'
  },
  {
    userId: '611de1937df523af1ffd42f8',
    socketId: 'J-J30EWlhVeDkqJ6AAAd'
  }
]
J-J30EWlhVeDkqJ6AAAd //this is receiver's socket id in server
```

Client Side console

```
R0aR7RPkiaH-Ai8qAAAR //client socket id
611dc227ccbf0ca9d2193b37 // both side unique userId
611de1937df523af1ffd42f8
```

So it's really weird,consider both the socket id are correct but I still can't receive message through io.to(socketId) . I have worked on these for hours , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging for a while , I managed to solve the issue,hope this could help other people who struggle at this.

So I accidentally connect to socket twice .

```
socket.current = await io(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_PORT)
```

Base on my test I think it will only connect once and after that even you can successfully passed your message, the socketId will be fixed on the orginally one , but the server will contain your last socketId.

That's why I failed to use io.to(socketId), and because I left the other connect command on other function , so I think no one can answer this question. Thanks anyway!